# Writing dapper General Service to make a connect to database and read the data from table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, service, dapper

I am trying to write a general dapper service method that can fecth all the data from a SQL table after connection string and table name has been provided.

I have following Dapper Service Code.

The dbConnectionString let's the code connect to database using project settings.

I have tried following but I am missing the type of result or method signature to be used correctly.

```
   public class DapperService : IDapperService
       {        
        private readonly string dbConnectionString;

        public DapperService(IOptions<ProjectSettings> config)
        {
            dbConnectionString = config.Value.DbConnection;
        }

        public async List<T> GetTableData(string tableName, CommandType commondaType = CommandType.Text)
        {
            using IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
            return await db.QueryAsync<T>(commandType: CommandType).toList();
        }
```

Comment: Dapper expects an actual query. Maybe use Dapper.Contrib?

Answer (score 0):

Right, so there's two things here. Firstly, we need a query (assuming your provider doesn't support "table direct"); `"select * from " + tableName` would probably be a good start, although if the table name is exotic it might need escaping, and escape rules are provider-specific. You should never accept table names from user input, since table names cannot be parameterized.

Second, we need to know a `T` at some point, so either the *service* or the *method* needs to be generic - i.e. `DapperService<T>` or `GetTableData<T>`; I'd probably go with the service (including the interface, `IDapperService<T>`) - but ultimately that is your choice.

Alternatively you could provide that separately, or use a tool like "Dapper.Contrib" which does most of this already.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach I can see is [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib), But it offers more features like

```
T Get<T>(id);
IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>();
int Insert<T>(T obj);
int Insert<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool Update<T>(T obj);
bool Update<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool Delete<T>(T obj);
bool Delete<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool DeleteAll<T>();
```

You can add repository pattern to make internal implementation more abstract, but its completely base on your requirement.
This will be very good base class if you want to follow repository pattern with dapper and contrib
finally this is very good [repository pattern implementation with unit of work](https://github.com/timschreiber/DapperUnitOfWork)

```
public class Repository<T> 
{
    protected IDbTransaction _transaction { get; private set; }
    protected IDbConnection _connection { get { return _transaction.Connection; } }

    public Repository(IDbTransaction transaction)
    {
        SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper = (type) => $"[{type.Name}]";
        _transaction = transaction;
    }

    public bool Delete(T obj)
    {
        return _connection.Delete(obj,_transaction);
    }
    public Task<bool> DeleteAsync(T obj)
    {
        return _connection.DeleteAsync(obj, _transaction);
    }

    public bool Delete(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        return _connection.Delete(list, _transaction);
    }

    public Task<bool> DeleteAsync(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        return _connection.DeleteAsync(list, _transaction);
    }
    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return _connection.Get<T>(id, _transaction);
    }

    public Task<T> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        return _connection.GetAsync<T>(id, _transaction);
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _connection.GetAll<T>(_transaction);
    }
    public Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return _connection.GetAllAsync<T>(_transaction);
    }

    public int Insert(T obj)
    {
        return (int)_connection.Insert(obj, _transaction);
    }

    public Task<int> InsertAsync(T obj)
    {
        return _connection.InsertAsync(obj, _transaction);
    }

    public int Insert(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        return (int)_connection.Insert(list, _transaction);
    }

    public Task<int> InsertAsync(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        return _connection.InsertAsync(list, _transaction);
    }

    public bool Update(T obj)
    {
        return _connection.Update(obj, _transaction);
    }

    public Task<bool> UpdateAsync(T obj)
    {
        return _connection.UpdateAsync(obj, _transaction);
    }

    public bool Update(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        return _connection.Update(list, _transaction);
    }
    public Task<bool> UpdateAsync(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        return _connection.UpdateAsync(list, _transaction);
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> Query(string command, object parameters = null, CommandType cmdType = CommandType.Text)
    {
        return _connection.Query<T>(
                   command,
                   parameters,
                   commandType: cmdType,
                   commandTimeout: 120,
                   transaction: _transaction);
    }
    public Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync(string command, object parameters = null, CommandType cmdType = CommandType.Text)
    {
        return _connection.QueryAsync<T>(
                   command,
                   parameters,
                   commandType: cmdType,
                   commandTimeout: 120,
                   transaction: _transaction);
    }
}
```